# Checking the size or length of a string array in java

Tags: java

I have this

```
String p[] = null;
```

I need to check whether its size/length is `null` or not. Something like

```
if (p.length == null)
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot check length of `null`. Also, `length` returns an `int` which can never be `null`. Just do

```
if (p == null) {
    // There is no array at all.
} else if (p.length == 0) {
    // There is an array, but there are no elements.
}
```

Or just instantiate it instead of keeping it `null`.

```
String[] p = new String[0];
```

Then you can do:

```
if (p.length == 0) {
    // There are no elements.
}
```

#### See also:

- [The Java Tutorials - Arrays](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: I can't help but wonder what criteria is not being met for someone to get a comment like the above ("thanks... gr8 help") but not to get accepted (?)... apparently @athresh DOES have some acceptance criteria... just very strict, I suppose (?)

Comment: @Code: OP isn't/wasn't really familiar with how Stack Overflow is supposed to be used.

Answer (score 3):

A null reference does not *have* a length. Any attempt to access any of its members will result in a `NullPointerException`.

An array object has a length of type `int`, which means it can be `0`, but not `null`. There is a difference between a null reference of an array type and a reference pointing at an array object of length zero.

Perhaps you want to do this:

```
if(p==null || p.length==0)
```

Since `||` is a short-circuiting operator, this will return `false` for both null references and arrays of length zero, and not throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: thanks a loooooooooooooooooot... this is wat i needed... my code works... thanks again.......

Answer (score 2):

```
if (p == null)
```

the length value is calculated from the size of the array. If the array is null, then just check the object and not the length.

Comment: thanks a loooooooooooooooooot... this is wat i needed... my code works... thanks again.......

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean isUseless(String str)
{
    return str == null || str.length() == 0;
}
```

Usage pattern:

```
String s = null;
isUseless(s);
```

Returns `true`

Answer (score 1):

if a reference is null, you can't do any operations on it like accessing its methods. what i think you really need is

```
if (p == null) {
    // throw some exception
} else {
   if (p.length == 0) {
       // your logic goes here
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks a loooooooooooooooooot... this is wat i needed... my code works... thanks again.......

Answer (score 0):

You can't check a `null` objects members, this isn't possible, and once you have an actual instance of the `String[]` the `length` and `count` will be 0 as this is their default value.

You can initialize this as

`String[] p = new String[6];`

Then once you've initialized this you can call `p.length`

Comment: so do i need to initialize it like String p[]=new String[6] ??

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I use the `ArrayUtils.getLength` from the apache's commons lang lib.

It checks the nullity and returns a size (`0` for a `null` array).